# javascript print button

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem with my print button:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
input#hideme {
display:none;
}
}
</style>

<input type='button' id='hideme' onClick='window.print();' value='Print Receipt'>
```

When I open my application and click my print button,  it shows directly the print popup.
But when I cancel that print popup  and again try to click, the print button will not open the popup.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using Google Chrome.
It's a known issue. The browser sends the following error : `Ignoring too frequent calls to print().`.

For more details, [click here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50186).
Test your code in Firefox, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

it works fine I just tested it.

Do you have any other javascript somewhere?

EDIT: here's a test http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/RbNAX/ and it works perfectly in Safari, Firefox, IE(7 + 8), I haven't tested in Chrome, as Zakaria said, it could be that.